# If $f$ is an entire function for which $f^{-1}(B_r)$ is bounded for all $r >0$ then $\infty$ are removable singularity and pole

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{B}_r$ denote the closed disk $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \le r \}$. State whether $\infty$   is a removable singularity , pole , or essential singularity in the   following statement

> $f$  is  an entire   function  for  which $f^{-1}(B_r)$  is bounded  for  all  $r >0$

**My attempt** :Here  $\infty$   are both removable singularity and  pole

> Inverse  image  of  closed  unit disk  of  $f$  is bounded  so $f$  can not  have  essential  singularity at $\infty$

Removable  singularity :-

> Suppose  that $f$ is an entire function  that has  a  removable singularity  at infinity.Then there exist  an entire function  $g$  such that $g(z)= f(1/z)$   for all $z \in \mathbb{B_r}-\{0\}$.This implies  that $\lim_{z\to \infty} f(1/z)=f(0) $  which in turn  implies   that $g$   is bounded.Since  g is  a   bounded entire function, by liouville's theorem , $g$ is constant.Hence  $ f$ is constant $\implies  f^{-1}(B_r)$  is bounded  for  all  $r >0$

For pole

> take $f(z)= z$ , $g(z)=f(1/z)=1/z$   where $|z|\le r  >0$.  $g(z)$ has  pole  at $z=0   \implies  f$  has  a pole  at $\infty$
> $\implies  f^{-1}(B_r)$  is bounded  for  all  $r >0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example is fine. For removable singularity  the argument is  simpler. Any entire function with removable singularty at $\infty$ is a constant by Liouville's Theorem  because it is bounded.

If $f$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$ then it would take values in $B_1$ in every neighborhood of $\infty$ so $f^{-1} (B_1)$ is not bounded. Hence, $f$ cannot have an essential singularity at $\infty$.

Comment: @wasiu If it is a removable singularity then $f$ is a  consatnt. So $f^{-1}(B_r)=\mathbb C$ for large enough $r$ , contradicting the hypothesis.

Comment: okay got it ,thanks you @Kavi sir